# What sensors should be used to analyze vibration of a hard disk?

Tags: mechanical-engineering, electrical-engineering, motors, sensors

What kinds of sensors can be used to monitor the condition of a hard disk?

We want to be able to detect when a hard disk is not operating correctly.

Unexpected vibrations may be caused by spindle problems (probably low frequency), or by head crashing (high frequency).

Comment: howabout a microphone? preferably one with ultrasound capabilities. An accelerometer is also ok.

Comment: Is it possible for mechanical issues like these to be detected externally while not showing up in the drive diagnostics (SMART or performance)?

Comment: joojaa: An accelerometer would only detect very low frequency vibration, right?  I wonder what are the maximum freqs accelerometers detect?

Comment: You can get "Mechanical" accelerometers that are accurate up to frequencies of 10 or 20 kHz. Non-contact measurement systems like capacitance probes have a similar range. On the other hand laser Doppler vibrometers can measure at frequencies up to 10 MHz (at a price, of course!) if you really need to do that.

Comment: Well an axelerometer works mostly as a microphone would but a microphone has better ranges in some cases. by the way us @joojaa and it will ping me or any other user offocurse if you give their name and they are in the discussion chain.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are two types of sensors commonly used in hard disks to detect vibration and head crashing. They are:

1. **Accelerometer**: Accelerometers are used to detect sudden vibrations.
2. **Sudden Motion Sensors:** These are mostly used in Apple Notebooks to detect a sudden drop of a laptop and to disengage the hard drive. SMS system parks the hard drive and restart the hard drive when stability is detected. SMS include a triaxial accelerometers.

**References:**

- [Active hard-drive protection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Active_hard-drive_protection)
- [Sudden Motion Sensor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sudden_Motion_Sensor)
- [Mac notebooks: About the Sudden Motion Sensor](http://Mac%20notebooks:%20About%20the%20Sudden%20Motion%20Sensor)
- [Using Dual-Axis Accelerometers to Protect Hard Disk Drives](http://www.analog.com/library/analogDialogue/archives/39-11/hdd.html)
- [Accelerometers protect hard drives](http://www.eetimes.com/document.asp?doc_id=1271337)